# ActionBarCompat change effect in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm developing an App using Google's UI design guidelines, so I want to implement the ActionBar.

It must run on 2.2 so I decided to use the ActionBarCompat example.

Instead of using the iosched one, where the action bar is a layout included in an XML file, I decided to implement this using a helper:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mActivity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
}

public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mActivity.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
    R.layout.actionbar_compat);
  setupActionBar();
}
```

The problem is that, when my app is loading, it displays the default TitleBar and then, it changes to mine, so, there is an ugly effect...

Any way to avoid it?

Thank You!!

Comment: I have the same problem, any progress? :)

Comment: Nop, sorry... I'm going on in my app letting my-future-self to do something later :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the default theme of an application have the title bar and the theme is loaded before you run onCreate() method.

So, you need to change the theme of your activity (or your application) in the Manifest file with a theme that have no title bar.

For exemple :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: That's what I did, and I forgot to mark this question as solved... no pardon for me m(_ _)m. Thank you anyway!!

Comment: This solution doesn't seems to work for me. I've set Theme.Light.NoTitleBar for the application, and my custom style for my activity where I use the action bar. Setting Theme.Light.NoTitleBar for my activity throws "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It throws: E/AndroidRuntime(550): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features